# Accept boolean and String Type in Netbeans

Tags: string, boolean, subclass, abstract, abstract-methods

I am a little stumped at the moment. How do I write a method in a sub-class which overrides an abstract method and accepts only String and boolean values?

Answer (score 0):

All derived abstract Methods must have the same signature. Meaning the name and number of parameters as the method declared in superclass. So if your abstract class have String and boolean prameters you can do that by coping the signature in your subclass and adding your own definition.

Here is an example:

```
public void myMethod(String myString, Boolean b)
```

If you want to have different signature, then it doesn't make sense to extend the abstract class.

Also checkout this tutorial about abstract classes and methods in Java

http://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/java-abstract-class-method/